# Are there many users of PRADO out there?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks, prado

After making [some comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882/what-in-your-mind-is-the-best-php-mvc-framework#89095), I've been inspired to get some feedback on the PHP MVC framework [PRADO](http://pradosoft.com/). I've been using it for over a year now and I've very much enjoyed working with it, however I notice that throughout Stack Overflow, it doesn't seem to rate a mention when [symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) or [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) are being talked about as potential candidates for a framework.

Is anybody using Stack Overflow using PRADO now? If so, how do you find it? Has anyone used it in the past but left it behind, and if so, why? Can anybody appraise its strengths and weaknesses against Cake or symfony?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first time I looked into PRADO, I spent about 10 days using it and kept saying to myself: "This framework is amazing!". A couple of months later, I started working on a big project where the customer had chosen to use PRADO... And Hell began... As long as we kept using PRADO's base components, everything was perfect and development was fast. But as soon as the customer wanted an out-of-the-box thing, we literaly spent 2 to 3 times the amount of time we would have done it with another framework. And I'm not talking about big customizations. The PRADO framework forces the application to have a particular structure and workflow. If that logic is not working for you, then check out another framework.

Comment: This ended up being my exact experience. It was great for a while, then became a nightmare. I wish you'd answered this a year ago! Would've saved me a couple of months of horror ;)

Answer (score 3):

I've played with PRADO some, but I felt that if I'm going to be forced into post-back-hell i might as well do it on the platform that it was built for in the beginning - .NET, other then that PRADO is relatively "untalked" about in the blogs, etc. I don't know why really though.

Comment: What is it about post-backs that you find hellish and what alternatives are you aware of? I've found post-backs to be pretty clumsy in the time i've worked with PRADO and with .NET, but haven't really known any alterantives.

Answer (score 3):

I found that the active controls were pretty slick. It makes doing all kinds of ajaxy things really easy. Unfortunately, when you need to do something slightly different, it's pretty obfuscated and difficult to figure out what's up. I felt like I often got something simple and great working, and then one small additional requirement would require me to tear the whole thing apart and come up with a much more complicated solution.

Answer (score 3):

Prado is dead now. Also the documentation is poor.

Comment: It's doing great for a dead framework :)

Answer (score 2):

I think Prado never really caught on because it's an event-driven framework, which is a bit hard to wrap your head around. Especially for the many PHP developers coming from a more procedural background.

Answer (score 2):

PRADO would have been my choice for a framework if I hadn't run across QCodo.  I like the event-driven approach -- QCodo just suits me more.

Comment: I too use QCodo and love it. It's QCubed (http://qcu.be) fork is the one that's actively developed at the moment.

Comment: Nice to know there's an actively developed fork - I was starting to give up hope on it.

Answer (score 0):

We are working with PRADO framework since 4 years. 
We are developing huge (+4000 programs) web apps for e-Goverment with Oraracle and MySql databases containing more than 60 millon records. As infrastructure for development we use SVN+TRAC+ our own tools for project control AND phpEdit w/tortoiseSVN as client tools. 
Currently we are thinking on changing to Yii.